# Is there a method for information transfer without copying the data?

Tags: algorithms, information-theory

What I mean is, if in real life I had an object and I gave it to you, I would not have it anymore. I did not give you a copy of the object.

Is there a way to do that with information?

Comment: quantum information perhaps (teleportation and no-cloning)

Comment: It's perfectly possible to mechanically transfer a single instance of data - just hand someone a flash drive. The reason this isn't generally implemented as a feature of a computer that can be programmed and performed repeatedly, is because it isn't particularly useful nowadays - certainly it is less useful than transmitting a copy of the data over network wiring.

Comment: @Steve : agreed, the bits encoding the information have been mechanically transferred and are no longer where they came from. But is information also erased there (I am not insisting, just wondering :-))?

Comment: @FirstNameLastName, I think you'll probably find that the answer is a function only of philosophical tenets.

Comment: @Steve: quantum computers and their algorithms (based upon theorems like Bell's one) are real. But agreed: it becomes vague in that information (just like entropy and time) only increases in the universe. But then *where* is information :-)? I am happy to take a step back.

Comment: (There used to be carrying around/handing over storage media: carved stone, papyri, ticker tape, tape reels, Blu-ray, flash memory….) Define *transfer*.

Comment: @greybeard OP told what was 'meant' ... I suggest to add quantum-computing tag ... it might help

Comment: As greybeard's comment indicates, this question is, in fact, about the definition of "information transfer".